# Render React components from array

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of references to react components. How do I render them?

```
myArray = [Component1, Component2, Component3];
```

I'm looking for the render function that, when given the array, would render this:

```
<div>
  <Component1 />
  <Component2 />
  <Component3 />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through each of the element of the array, where each element is the component and render it as a JSX element.

Like this, e.g. If `myComponents` contains `[MyComponent1, MyComponent2, MyComponent3]` then

```
renderMyComponents(myComponents){
     return myComponents.map((MyComponent, index) => {
          return (
               <li key={index}>
                   <MyComponent />
               </li>
          )
     });
}
```

Here is the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9dktLzf/).

Comment: This doesn't help, as the components are not of the same type. The render function doesn't know anything about the array, just that it's an array of react components.

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle? All components are different in the array. Where are you getting an array from? How the array is being passed?

Comment: Oh, my apologies... I misread the code and didn't realize at first that MyComponent was the variable from the map() function. This works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, It seems bit misleading because normally variables are named in camelCase letters but here I was also rendering it as an element `<MyComponent />` so decided not to use camelCase.

Answer (score 2):

In react 16 > , You can just return an array of components inside render like this:-

```
render(){
      return this.state.myArray
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {myArray}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This won't work for OPs case. It will only work when array contains react element.

Answer (score -2):

If i right understood the problem - Try set component to some variables before `return` into the `render` methods, and then into div, call this variables like object:

```
render:
myArray = [Component1, Component2, Component3];
var myComp1 = myArray[0];
var myComp2 = myArray[1];
var myComp3 = myArray[2];
.....some code
return
....some code
<div>
  {myComp1}
  {myComp2}
  {myComp3}
</div>
```

**Update** ***React 16*** : (in this way no excess DIV wrapper in DOM all elements like siblings on one level)

```
render(): {
  const myArray = [Component1, Component2, Component3];
  .....some code
  return
  ....some code
  <>
    myArray.map((component) => {
      return({component})
    })
  </>
}
```